# Why is the protagonist of "Shortsighted" named Calvin Hobbes?

Tags: inspiration, thaddeus-howze

In the story ["Shortsighted"](https://ebonstorm.medium.com/shortsighted-cfe13d2ab8d5) by Thaddeus Howze, the protagonist's name is revealed to be Calvin Hobbes.

This seems a reference to the well-known cartoon characters [Calvin and Hobbes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calvin_and_Hobbes). Was this intended, and if so, why?

Comment: Given that the writer is relatively little known (and thus unlikely to be the subject of much literary analysis) and still living it would seem asking him is probably the best answer. Don't forget that the cartoon Calvin and Hobbes are themselves named after philosopher Thomas Hobbes and theologian John Calvin.

Comment: @DJClayworth https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13347/june-2021-topic-challenge-thaddeus-howze-stories

Comment: @DJClayworth - He's on Twitter *hourly*. He hasn't logged in to SFF for months, not even since he was asked to step down as moderator.